# pg gem won't install for Heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy to Heroku with a Ruby on Rails app I created. I created it using sqlite and am trying to switch over to Postgres so I can Heroku. I have searched for answers to the error I'm receiving and nothing works. Here's what I've done:

Gemfile:

```
group :production do
   gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'pg'
```

Database.yml:

```
    development:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: utf8
      database: classsap_development
      pool: 5
      username:
      password:

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: classsap_test
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: classsap_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

cucumber:
  <<: *TEST
```

Then I push to Git and try to run bundle install (or many, many variations of this) and I get this error:

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

If I push/run bundle install/push to Heroku with the "gem 'pg'" in my Gemfile, the app deploys but any page that needs to use the database won't work. How can I get pg to install, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you sign up for the PG add in?

Comment: Do you mean on Heroku? I have a Postgres add-on attached to my app, otherwise I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI to anyone else with this question, I figured out some answers and it took quite a while and lot of trial/error. I had to use this:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install
```

then I had to run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```